# How can I delete duplicate albums from my photo library?

Tags: iphone, ios

Since I updated to iOS 5 I have 4 photo albums in the Photo App. Camera Roll, Photo Stream, Photo Library & iPhone.  Photo Library & iPhone are identical. How do I delete one or the other?

Answer (score 2):

Camera Roll, Photo Stream and Photo Library are system albums and cannot be deleted. (Photo Library is a smart album and displays all your photos, regardless of where they actually are).

Your photos are probably only in the iPhone album, if you delete it, they're probably gone. However to delete it hit the "Edit" button, then the little red minus in front of the album you want to delete.

If you added the album to your phone by syncing it from your computer, you won't be able to remove it from the phone. In that case connect your phone to iTunes select the photos tab and uncheck the album you want to remove.

Comment: thnx. i'll try that

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me after having the same issue after upgrading to iOS 6 from iOS 5 where photos were showing up twice in the Photo Library. Note that this was on a PC, not a Mac:

1. Moved all files in the My Pictures folder to the Recycle Bin.
2. Synced all picture folders with the iPhone using iTunes.
3. Unselected Sync Photos in iTunes and said yes to "Remove all synced pictures from iPhone?"
4. Restored all pictures from the Recycle Bin to the My Pictures folder.
5. Selected Sync Photos from My Pictures in iTunes and synced iPhone.

Now all photos show up only once in the Photo Library.  Note as stated above, the Photo Library is a system folder that provides a consolidated view of all pictures stored in the seperate folders.

Answer (score 0):

That's how I do it:

1. On my PC desktop, I right clicked and created a new folder. I named it "Empty folder".
2. I plugged in my phone to computer, opened iTunes.
3. Clicked on my phone on the left
4. Clicked on "photos" on the top
5. Clicked the box "Sync Photos with"
6. Choose the dropdown and "choose folder"
7. Click "desktop" option
8. Click on the folder that you created and named whatever you named it.
9. Click "apply/sync"
10. After it finishes, it will have cleared the old cache completely.

Now you can go back and sync the folders you want and it will ONLY have those photos.

Comment: How does this solve the problem described in the question?